# Why Sitemesh doesn't work in my project (Spring)?

Tags: java, html, spring, jakarta-ee, sitemesh

In my project I want to use the Sitemesh, for each page there will be a menu template. Previously, he worked when he was in `web.xml`. But now i deleted `web.xml` and I want to implement it without `web.xml`.  correctly implemented the site mesh, it just does not work for me

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

import org.sitemesh.builder.SiteMeshFilterBuilder;
import org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter;

public class MySiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {

  @Override
  protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {

            builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/homeDecorator.jsp") 

           .addDecoratorPath("/allStudents", "/WEB-INF/decorators/homeDecorator.jsp")
           .addDecoratorPath("/addStudents.jsp", "/WEB-INF/decorators/addStudentDecorator.jsp");
    }    
}
```

Code in web.xml which i delete

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: So you hav a filter... NIce, now register it... Without registering it with the container (which what the `web.xml` did) it won't work...

Comment: you can help to write the code, I can not implement

Comment: Sure you can... You decided to delete the `web.xml` so you must have done some investigation what the replacement of that is in Java code...

Comment: I'm just just learning to programming, and I was advised to remove web.xml Everything worked in Web.xml.  But I have to pass this task within 30 minutes, you can help to implement it. Then at night I will start to study further and understand how it is done.

Comment: Giving time constraints isn't going to help you get an answer quicker... Also just providing you with the code to load the sitemesh filter won't help as you need more... You are using Spring so you need a `DispatcherServlet` and/or `ContextLoaderListener` as well. So without actually seeing the web.xml writing an answer (or let us make your school assignment) is not possible.